# Excel VBA - copy multiple columns from 2 workbooks into 1 workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two workbooks that have data in multiple columns that I want copied and put into a new workbook that contains this macro.  Basically I want to be able to open the current workbook, "z", run the macro, and have the data move/copy over from the other two existing workbooks.

I have been searching around here and looking at different ideas from different posts, and think I have pretty much figured this out but am running into a "Run-time error 1004" when I run this code.  The error happens at the first y.Range line, and I have yet to figure out why.

I have successfully been able to pull the data from "x" workbook but not "y".

I am new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

```
Sub SellPrice()

Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, z As Worksheet, LastRow&

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\tsmith\Desktop\SellPrice\PRODUCT.XLS")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\tsmith\Desktop\SellPrice\GrossProfit.xls")

Set x = Workbooks("PRODUCT.XLS").Worksheets("ProductFile")
Set y = Workbooks("GrossProfit.xls").Worksheets("Sellprice")
Set z = Workbooks("SellPriceMacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

x.Range("B4:B" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("C4:C" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

LastRow = y.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

y.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how you put the worksheet before you used `Range()`? (`y.Range(...)`) - you need to do that any time you use `Cells()`, `Rows.Count`, and `Columns.Count` (and other ranges). Otherwise, it's going to look to whatever the ActiveSheet is, and use that. When you mix inactive sheets with active sheets, you'll get an error.

```
Sub SellPrice()

Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, z As Worksheet, LastRow&

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\tsmith\Desktop\SellPrice\PRODUCT.XLS")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\tsmith\Desktop\SellPrice\GrossProfit.xls")

Set x = Workbooks("PRODUCT.XLS").Worksheets("ProductFile")
Set y = Workbooks("GrossProfit.xls").Worksheets("Sellprice")
Set z = Workbooks("SellPriceMacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

x.Range("B4:B" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("C4:C" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

LastRow = y.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

y.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
y.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Copy z.Cells(z.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading your response incorrectly, the code should work because I put the workbook before Range, `y.Range`

Comment: Can this be cleaned up to get rid of the `Cells`,  `Rows.Count`, etc?  I even tried running this removing all of workbook "x" lines but it still comes up with the same error.  I'm thinking maybe Workbook "y"?

Comment: @T.Smith is it just the copy/paste to SO, or does your code also have `.end(x1up)` ...note that it's a `1` and not an `l`.